# Speed up spatial intersection with R sf by specifying that there can only be unique matches

Tags: r, intersection, sf

I have a set of spatial points representing office locations. I intersect it with polygons representing regions to know in which region each office is. I'm using R with `sf::st_intersects(offices_shapefile, regions_shapefile)` to get that information. I have millions of offices and thousands of regions in my data, making calls to `sf::st_intersects` very time-consuming.

An office can be in only one region. I guess that, technically, it could be on the border of multiple regions, but in that case I'm OK with assigning whichever of these regions to the office. To speed up the intersection process, it would be great if `sf::st_intersects` could go to next office as soon as it finds a region match for the current one, and avoid going through the whole set of regions for each office.

I don't know anything about the internals of `sf`, but would it be possible to specify match-uniqueness to `sf` so it does an intersection faster?

Comment: have you looked at the library 'terra'? Apparently it is written in C++ and is quicker in execution than sf.  Might be an alternative.

Answer (score 5):

`st_intersects(points, polys)` builds a "spatial index" of the polygons, which makes finding the intersections a bit like finding a word in an alphabetic index. It doesn't have to test the point against the geometry of every polygon, because a lot of the polygons are eliminated very quickly by using the index, in the same way that you don't have to scan every word on every page of an alphabetic book index to find a word.

So I don't think the optimisation you suggest would win very much. Depending on how the index is built, the code might only being doing expensive tests on three or four polygons maximum for the usual sort of administrative polygon division shapes (its based on the point being in the bounding box of the polygons, but with nested grouped bounding boxes so the code doesn't even have to loop over bounding boxes. Look up spatial indexing methods, its very cool...).

Hence if the code is only testing on average 1 or 2 polygons for each point, your constraint on matching one and then terminating might get you a doubling of speed, but not much more.

A more convenient way to speed this up would be to split your points into sets and run parallel computations - you might get an 8x speedup on a standard PC (unless the `st_intersects` code is already using parallel process...), and massive speedups if you can use a cluster.

Comment: The point-in-polygon tests are themselves indexed and are essentially free after the first one.